# reference to nested class (struct) in header file

Tags: c++, class, reference, header-files

If I have a nested struct in class like this:

```
(a.h file)
class A{
public:
    struct B{...};
};
```

And I want to pass argument that reference to A::B in other .h file. How I do that?
I want to do:

```
(b.h file)
class B{
    randomMethod(A::B arg0);
};
```

I heard that including other .h file in .h file isn't good practice. So I tried to add some class declaration before Class B, but it doesn't work.
I tried:

```
class A::B;
class B{...}
or 
class A;
class A::B;
class B{...}
```

Comment: "I heard that including other .h file in .h file isn't good practice." What? Where did you hear that?

Comment: Related: [Reason for not allowing forward declarations of nested class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674653/reason-for-not-allowing-forward-declarations-of-nested-class)

Answer (score 0):

> I heard that including other .h file in .h file isn't good practice.

You may have misunderstood, or you've heard misinformation. Including headers in headers is normal.

> And I want to pass argument that reference to A::B in other .h file. How I do that?

You must define the outer class that declares the nested class. The most convenient and least error prone way to achieve that is to include a file that defines the class.

However, it is indeed better minimise the number of inclusions. You can avoid including the definition of the outer class by defining the other nested class outside it - so that it is no longer nested. You can still define a member type alias within the outer class. For example:

```
namespace A_ns {
    struct B; // declaration only
}

class B {
    // doesn't requre definition of A nor A::B
    return_type randomMethod(A_ns::B arg0);
};

namespace A_ns {
    struct B{}; // defined outside of A

    class A {
    public:
        // type alias instead of nested class
        using B = A_ns::B;
    };
}
```